# Matlab: How to label subplots that contain polarplot() plots?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm producing a figure in MATLAB that consists of a grid of subplots, each of which contains a polar plot. I would like to label this grid by row and column.

Column labels are easy, using the `title` text for each plot.

For row labels, with Cartesian plots I'd simply abuse the y-axis labels of the first column of subplots, but with polar plots there is (reasonably) no ylabel.
How can I add row labels?

Note that I am using the new `polarplot()` function that was introduced in MATLAB 2016a, so most existing answers out there that refer to `polar()` do not apply.

Comment: I want one y-label per row of subplots (i.e. it's a label for that row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty hacky, but if you really want, you could create the ylabels in a temporary axes, copy them over to the polarplots, and then get rid of the temporary axes.

**Example:**

```
% Setup some polarplots
m=2;n=3;        % Number of plots to make
padding = 0.5;  % Determines space between labels and plots
atmp=axes;
figure;
for j=1:m
    for k=1:n
        subplot(m,n,sub2ind([n,m],k,j));       
        polarplot(0);

        % Add labels
        if j==1 % Top labels
            htmp=xlabel(atmp, 'Top Label');
            htmp.Units='normalized';
            htmp.Position(2)= 1+padding;
            copyobj(htmp,gca);
        end
        if k==1 % Left Labels
            htmp=ylabel(atmp, 'Left Label');
            htmp.Units='normalized';
            htmp.Position(1)= -padding;
            copyobj(htmp,gca);
        end
    end
end
close(atmp.Parent); % Close the temporary axes
```

Which creates:

[image: image of subplots with labels]

Comment: As you say, it is hacky, but this being Matlab it's probably the only way for now. Thank you so much :-)

Comment: Thank you. It's sad that this is not supported. I've never liked Mathworks' approach to plotting.